# Cannot properly set "type" property for section node for ASP.NET custom configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, configuration-files

I am trying to retrieve values from a custom configuration from a Web.config file while running one of my web projects in Visual Studio 2012.

When I attempt to execute this code:

```
classes.Globals.ASPNET2Configuration configInfoRepresentativeAddress =  
              (classes.Globals.ASPNET2Configuration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfig/RepresentativeAddresses");
```

I get this error:

**Error: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for customConfig/RepresentativeAddresses: Could not load type 'pri001___P_Website.classes.Globals.ASPNET2Configuration'. (C:\[pathToProjectFiles]\web.config line 9)**
 *Please note: the "P" in the default namespace stands for something else - I removed the actual value for this posting*

I am pretty certain that my issue lies with the `type` property in the `section` node of the Web.config file. I have researched and tried several different values for this but all failed. The Globals.cs file, which contains the configuration classes is in a folder called "classes".
This is part of the directory structure to help clarify:

[image: Project Directory Tree]

Here is the markup:

```
 <configuration>
      <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="customConfig">
      <section name="RepresentativeAddresses" 
               requirePermission="false" 
               type="pri001___P_Website.classes.Globals.ASPNET2Configuration" 
               allowDefinition="Everywhere" 
               allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <customConfig>
    <RepresentativeAddresses>
      <Representatives>
        <add representativeName="biff" eMailAddress="biff@foo.com"/>
        <add representativeName="dick" eMailAddress="dick@foo.com"/>
        <add representativeName="rod" eMailAddress="rod@foo.com"/>
      </Representatives>
    </RepresentativeAddresses>
  </customConfig>
```

Here is the code for my configuration classes:

```
 namespace pri001___P_Website.classes
{
    public static class Globals
    {      
        public class ASPNET2Configuration_Representative : ConfigurationElement
        {
            [ConfigurationProperty("representativeName")]
            public string representativeName
            {
                get { return this["representativeName"] as string; }
            }
            [ConfigurationProperty("eMailAddress")]
            public string eMailAddress
            {
                get { return this["eMailAddress"] as string; }
            }
        }

        public class ASPNET2Configuration_RepresentativeCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
        {
            public ASPNET2Configuration_Representative this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    return base.BaseGet(index) as ASPNET2Configuration_Representative;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
                        base.BaseRemoveAt(index);

                    this.BaseAdd(index, value);
                }
            }

            protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
            {
                return new ASPNET2Configuration_Representative();
            }

            protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
            {
                return ((ASPNET2Configuration_Representative)element).representativeName;
            }
        }

        public class ASPNET2Configuration : ConfigurationSection
        {
            public static ASPNET2Configuration GetConfig()
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfig/RepresentativeAddresses") as ASPNET2Configuration;
            }

            [ConfigurationProperty("Representatives")]
            public ASPNET2Configuration_RepresentativeCollection Representatives
            {
                get { return this["Reprensentatives"] as ASPNET2Configuration_RepresentativeCollection; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the `type` property's value in fact my problem, or is there something else amiss?

Comment: interresting namespace. almost smells generated. You could try augmenting the type with the full library information, eg; "{type}, {assembly FQN}"

Comment: i made the assembly (pri001-P_Website.dll) strongly typed and then changed the `TYPE` node to `type="pri001___P_Website.classes.Globals.ASPNET2Configuration, pri001-P_Website, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5faeb48aeb1ecbc6"` but it says that it "Could not load type..."

Comment: i got it to work by changing the `ASPNET2Configuration` class name to `ASPNET2ConfigurationSection` and modifying the `type` property of the `section name` node in the web.config to `pri001___P_Website.ASPNET2ConfigurationSection`. i also moved the custom configuration classes into the asp.net page for simplicity; will move it out later but it's working now.